# XPATH/XSL : Unable to retrieve node elements using node-set

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to join two tables together and output a single table.
Table "Conventional Display" holds the value "BASICSA " which needs to match table "All Rates" that holds the data for the value.

Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ConvDispData.xsl"?>
<Rates xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <TableList>
    <Table name="Conventional Display">
      <Tbody>
        <Tr>
          <Td>BASICSA </Td>
        </Tr>
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
    <Table name="All Rates">
      <Tbody>
        <Tr>
          <Td>BASICSA   </Td>
          <Td>balanceLimit001  </Td>
          <Td>rateamou1   </Td>
        </Tr>
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
  </TableList>
</Rates>
```

and below is my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxsl"
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="TABLE_NAME">All Rates</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ALL_RATES_TR" select="//Table[@name=$TABLE_NAME]/Tbody/Tr" />

    <xsl:variable name="CONV_TABLE_NAME">Conventional Display</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="TITLE1">Conventional Display</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="COLUMN1">WT-RATE-NUMBER</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="COLUMN2">WT-AMOUNT-TO-CHECK(1)</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="COLUMN3">WT-SPLIT-TIER-RATE(1)</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="REC_PER_PAGE">10</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <Rates>
            <TableList>
                <Table name="{$CONV_TABLE_NAME}"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblDeposit">
                    <RecordPerPage>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$REC_PER_PAGE"/>
                    </RecordPerPage>
                    <xsl:call-template name="BuildHeader"/>
                    <Tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Table[@name=$CONV_TABLE_NAME]/Tbody/Tr">
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </Tbody>
                </Table>
            </TableList>
        </Rates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="BuildHeader">
        <Thead>

            <Tr>
                <Td class="tdDepositHeaderType">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$COLUMN1"/>
                </Td>
                <Td class="tdDepositHeaderRates">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$COLUMN2"/>
                </Td>
                <Td class="tdDepositHeaderRates">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$COLUMN3"/>
                </Td>
            </Tr>
        </Thead>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Tr">
        <xsl:param name="PreClass"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Position">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="Class">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$PreClass=''">
                    <xsl:call-template name="SectionClass">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Pos">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$Position"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$PreClass"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>


        <xsl:variable name="RATEID" select="Td[1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="MATCHEDTD" select="ext:node-set($ALL_RATES_TR)/Tbody" />
            <Tr>
                <xsl:attribute name="Class">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Class"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <Td class="tdDepositType">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$RATEID"/>
                </Td>

                <Td class="tdDepositType">
                    <xsl:value-of select="MATCHEDTD[2]"/>
                </Td>
                <Td class="tdDepositType">
                    <xsl:value-of select="MATCHEDTD[3]"/>
                </Td>
            </Tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="SectionClass">
        <xsl:param name="Pos"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$Pos mod 2 != 0">TOdd</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>TEven</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My issue with this code is here:

Using LiquidStudio, I can see that if I do ext:node-set($ALL_RATES_TR), I get a sequence of values which is Tbody. however whenever I try to use any XPath to retrieve the finer values of the Tbody, the selection returns empty.

I do not understand why it can return empty, even though the path should be correct.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to use `node-set` here. Your `$ALL_RATES_TR` is referencing nodes in the input document, and so is already node set.

Also, `$ALL_RATES_TR` selects the `Tr` element for the table, so it doesn't make sense to try and select a `TBody` under it. You probably mean to select `Td` like so...

```
<xsl:variable name="MATCHEDTD" select="$ALL_RATES_TR/Td" />
```

Having done that, the other issue is that you have forgotten to add the `$` prefix when trying to access the `MATCHEDTD`. You were doing `<xsl:value-of select="MATCHEDTD[2]"/>` when you should have been doing this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$MATCHEDTD[2]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think that fixed it. Turns out that Liquid studio wasn't working properly... I've fixed my code and ran it in a web browser and it works fine, but doesn't work in Liquid studio.